# What flavor of Object Pascal is used in the Nexus DB report Designer?

Tags: documentation, delphi, report-designer, nexusdb

I use a software called RentalDesk NX that is built on top of Nexus DB.  According to the help manual for Report Designer, I need to code in Object Pascal, but none of the functions I can find referenced online (such as RightStr, StrToDate, or YearOf) seem to work at all.

I've been working on a report for my accounting department and cannot find a good way to do date math.  Does anyone have any insight as to what resource may actually be helpful to me?

I have already crossposted to the RentalDesk NX user community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RentalDesk NX report engine is based on digital metaphors' report engine see https://www.digital-metaphors.com/
The developers guide may help RBDeveloperGuide.zip or the learning Report Builder part of the web site https://www.digital-metaphors.com/download/learning_reportbuilder.html

As for the actual flavour of object pascal, I believe that it's based on remote objects Pascal script - but the best place to ask is probably the digital metaphors' news group news.digital-metaphors.com.

I don't know if you have a support contract for your copy of RentalDesk NX, but that would be IMHO the quickest route to specific questions e.g RightStr doesn't exist in Pascal script, you use Copy(string, start, end);

Comment: Thank you for that extra link.  I'll play with that information first, then consider the support contract.  Your team has always been great and responsive, my department just hasn't been allowed the budget we need to expand in the ways we would like to.